# Dihedral group presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I am solving the following question from Aluffi. I am stuck on showing that this is the actual presentation of $D_{2n}$.

Question:

Describe generators and relations for dihedral groups $D_{2n}$.

My solution:

Claim:

$D_{2n} = \ \langle r,s : r^n = s^2 = e, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$

I am confused on how to show that this generates $D_{2n}$. The book gives the following hint:

To see that these relations really determine $D_{2n}$, use them to show that any product $x^{i_1}y^{i_2}x^{i_3}x^{i_4}\ldots$ equals $x^iy^j$ for some $i,j$. The thing I am confused about is that how do we show this do we have to proceed by induction on $i_m$. I haven't seen this before. Can someone provide me with worked up version for $D_{2n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you are asking about doesn't require induction.   The trick is that  $rs=sr^{-1} $ is an "anti-commutativity" relation,  and allows you to switch the order of $r $ and $s$ (at a price, so to speak).

To take a very simple example,  $srs=s(rs)=s (sr^{\color{blue}{-1}})=s^2r^{-1}=r^{n-1}$.

It's pretty clear that this sort of swapping will enable us to gather all the  $s $'s and $r $'s together,  so that everything can be written in the form $s^ar^b $.

Incidentally this immediately gives a bound on the size of the group.

Comment: Yes, sure that is clear. But how can we prove that we can always swap every element.

Comment: Every time we encounter an $rs $ we can replace it with $sr^{-1} $.  So it's only a matter of time before all the $s $'s are together on one side, and the  $r $'s on the other.

Comment: A formal answer is work by induction on the sum of the number of factors of $r$ occurring to the left of any occurrence of $s$.  Work from the rightmost factor of $s$ and you'll see that this flip (combined with $s^2=e$) always reduces that sum, so your ability to perform the flip must eventually terminate.  The only way that can happen is for all factors of $s$ to be to the left of all factors of $r$.